# Ubuntu 13.4 on Dell n1710 USB install problems

Tags: 13.04

I really need some help with this. I couldn't find anything useful on the internet.

My goal is to check that my laptop is compatible with Ubuntu before I install and notice that i have no network for example.

Some info:

The machine is a Dell Inspiron N7110

I made a boot disk with Ubuntu 13.4 and anything i did while booting from it made the system to lock with a frozen cursor " _ " at the top left of the screen.

To make the USB I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.7 and afterwards i made a new one with http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download to reach the same conclusion.

When I select to run from USB, the OS loads up to that point and then hangs. I waited for 15-20 minutes just to see if it starts back up or it just takes long to load.

Ubuntu loads just fine from the USB on my old desktop, just not on the laptop.

[image]

Comment: That is weird since it is certified (http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201101-6957/).

Comment: I was unaware of this certification list.

I did send it for repair at dell twice since i have it. Last time they replaced the motherboard, could that be causing the issue?
I can take another picture with the whole screen if someone thinks it might help figure this out.

Comment: If there is more output to see, that might help, sure

Comment: A friend of mine recommended that i disable my dedicated GPU from the bios, so that i am only left with the integrated intel GPU. Afterwards install the linux nvidia drivers and try again with it enabled(if it works that far obviously).

Unfortunately i cannot change any settings of the sort from the bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. It seems that i had to disable ACPI from the advanced options menu(F6).

Other dell laptop models seem to require this for ubuntu to work.
Hope other people will find this helpfull in the future.
:D

Comment: Ok, maybe upgrade your BIOS when an uptdate is available and try again to boot with ACPI. It is probably a BIOS issue.